# @SessionAttribute in java/spring losing data?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

hi i have a problem with my project (small blog site) that i can't handle for a while

that's my LoginController
'''

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("currentUser")
public class LoginController {
    
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    
    @ModelAttribute("currentUser")
    public User setUpUserForm() {
        return new User();
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/login",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showLoginPage() {
        return "loginsite";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/login",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String userLogin(@ModelAttribute("currentUser") User user,ModelMap model,@RequestParam String login,@RequestParam String password) {
            if(userService.checkUserLoginData(login, password)==true) {
                user=userService.getUserByLogin(login);
                System.out.println("Logged in user");
                System.out.println("ID:"+user.getUserId());
                System.out.println("Login:"+user.getLogin());
                System.out.println("Password:"+user.getPassword());
                System.out.println("Email:"+user.getEmail());
                return "welcomesite";
            }else {
                model.put("message", "Check your login and password ! ");
                return "loginsite";
            }
    }
}
```

'''

that's my UserController

'''

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String posts() {
        return "redirect:/posts";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/createaccount",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showRegisterPage() {
        return "registrationpage";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/createaccount",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createAccount(ModelMap model,@RequestParam String login,@RequestParam String password,@RequestParam String email) {
        userService.addUser(new User(login,password,email));
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/login/accountsettings",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showAccountSettings(@SessionAttribute("currentUser") User user) {
        System.out.println("amil"+user.getEmail());
        return "userSettings";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(params="update",value="/login/accountsettings",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateAccountSettings(@SessionAttribute("currentUser") User user,@RequestParam String login,@RequestParam String password,@RequestParam String email) {
        user=userService.updateUser(new User(login,password,email));
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(params="delete",value="/login/accountsettings",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String deleteAccount(@RequestParam String login) {
        userService.deleteUser(login);
        return "redirect:/posts";
    }
```

'''

i would like to pass user data after logging in to next pages for ex /login/accountsettings or even to have user id to add post with his id as a creator of this post. After logging in everythink is okay i have complete user data but when im tring to get them in /login/accountsettings User is empty(full of null values).what am I doing wrong?

output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0nRH.png)

or I have a question, is there another better way to transfer user data until logging out?
Thanks for help!

Comment: `@SessionAttributes` isn't designed for that, it is for storing the user in the session for requests to the same controller. If you want to store the user, either use a session scoped bean (and remove the `@SessionAttributes`) or store it in the session yourself using `session.setAttribute`. Or simply retrieve it from the database and don't rely on the session at all (which would be the best solution imho). Also your login is simply reassigning a method parameter it doesn't do anything else.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks a lot! , so i'm going to  rebuild my controllers , 
how do I get information at / login / accountsetings that this particular user has arrived here and wants to do something with his account? 
Use sessions for this?